# Swift - How dynamically fixed UITableViewHeaderFooterView height size?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have just tried below lines of code, but I doesn't work correctly. I wonder that how can I provide this case for header or footer programmatically, may be using autolayout I don't know exactly which one solved my problem. I'm using xib file both of UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

If someone explain I would be great.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Dynamic sizing for the footer view
    if let footerView = tableView.tableFooterView {
        let height = footerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var footerFrame = footerView.frame

        if height != footerFrame.size.height {
            footerFrame.size.height = height
            footerView.frame = footerFrame
            tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UITableView calculates the HeaderFooter before they displayed, you can't update that height without calling reloadData() again.

Have you tried to use AutoLayout on those HeaderFooterViews?
I would set up the view from xib with the right constraint, and then:

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: IOS 8 can't be implemented

Comment: @ChildrenGreens what do you mean by that?

Comment: iOS8 constraint conflict，iOS9、iOS10 can be displayed properly

Comment: Sounds like you have different problem there, check you constraints..
It's supports iOS7+

Comment: do define the data source functions

``tableView:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection``
and
``tableView:heightForHeaderInSection``

instead of defining at viewDidLoad.